# How can I update existing notifications in Android ?

Tags: android, push-notification

I am using the following code for displaying notification . Upon displaying the notification , I go to the activity if I click in the notifications .

```
void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage){
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.noti, notificationTitle,System.currentTimeMillis());

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SmsActivity.class);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, notificationTitle,notificationMessage, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
       }
```

Now I want to update the text of notifications . How can I do that ?

Comment: i think you should post another notification with same id, then it will be updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the text of notification by sending different text in  `Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage)` method.

Comment: Can you explain further? Show some code if possible ! (In my case I need to update the ContentText on a button click -the button is in the notification- )

Answer (score 11):

You can try this

```
    //First time    
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notif_text))
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_alarm_2)
                        .setAutoCancel(false)
                        .setOngoing(running)
                        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                        .setContentIntent(
                                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 10, 
                                        new Intent(context, YourActivity.class)                                 
                                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP),
                                0)
                        )

            notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());

     //Second time

            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Comment: What is the value of id ?

Answer (score 7):

Send notification with same id:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem in approach suggested here is that if user already responded to this notification he could see it again, so you'd better to show it once instead.

So I wouldn't recommend to use this API at all in order to update your notifications.

If you are using it for that purpose you probably just exchange one bug for another.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing 0 as notification ID, send some other number and trigger another notification with the same ID.
The existing one will be updated.